# yum name mismatch between repos

Tags: yum

Trying to sort out the why (and how) to resolve a package dep issue...the issue being the package is already installed, just that the package name that's currently installed has a architecture bit at the end of the package name:

```
 --> Processing Dependency: libsmbios = 2.2.27-4.12.1.el6 for package: python-smbios-2.2.27-4.12.1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-smbios-2.2.27-4.12.1.el6.x86_64 (@dell-omsa-indep)
       Requires: libsmbios = 2.2.27-4.12.1.el6
       Removing: libsmbios-2.2.27-4.12.1.el6.x86_64 (@dell-omsa-indep)
           libsmbios = 2.2.27-4.12.1.el6
       Updated By: libsmbios-2.2.27-1908.9058.el6.x86_64 (dell-system-update_dependent)
           libsmbios = 2.2.27-1908.9058.el6
       Available: libsmbios-2.2.26-3.el6.i686 (epel)
           libsmbios = 2.2.26-3.el6

 [root@box yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep python-smbios
 python-smbios-2.2.27-4.12.1.el6.x86_64
```

My environment is puppet controlled and consists hundreds of boxes running yum update nightly, so a manual solution (i.e. --skip-broken) isn't a viable solution.

Comment: This is Dell's mistake and you need to yell very loudly at them.

Comment: I laughed pretty hard at that, but honestly...there has to be a way for me to rectify this somehow.

Comment: Hmm. If yelling doesn't work, you could speak in a normal voice. But the advice is otherwise 100% serious. This is a problem you should report to them.

Comment: opened a support ticket with them. here's hoping...

Comment: @EthanShrago did you hear anything back from Dell?

Comment: no, I get the feeling unless I have the premium support, this might go into a black hole...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:
http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2016-April/050490.html

short version
- disable the dell repository
- yum remove dell_ie_rac python-smbios

then yum update works again.

not sure what effect that'll have on the dell utilities, but I'd rather disable them than prevent server updates.